# Como consumir REST API do 4Shared utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, rest, libcurl

Tentei de todas as formas usar esse novo API DO 4SHARED, tanto com curl e file_get_contents e não consigo autenticar!

4Shared não disponibilizou nenhuma class igual  twitter e facebook disponibilza e estou com dificuldade pra fazer a requisição.

Documentação: http://www.4shared.com/developer/docs

Na documentação o método de iniciar a autenticação é POST, então usei o seguinte código:

```
$service_url = 'api.4shared.com/v1_2/oauth/initiate';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = ''; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
$resposta = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);

echo var_dump($resposta); 

//resposta: "message=Unauthorized.&code=400.0300&cause=Some of required parameters (oauth_consumer_key&oauth_signature&oauth_signature_method&oauth_timestamp&oauth‌​_nonce) absent"
```

Ai quando uso curl, o retorno é esse:

> message=Unauthorized.&code=400.0300&cause=Some of required parameters (oauth_consumer_key&oauth_signature&oauth_signature_method&oauth_timestamp&oauth‌​‌​_nonce) absent.

Se uso file_get_contents() o retorno é:

```
"400 bad request".
```

Essas informação nem tenho, o 4shared fornece apenas o "Auth Consumer Key" e "Auth Consumer Key Secret".

Alguém tem alguma ideia pra me ajudar?

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Não... mais  quando faço por file get contents da erro de "400 base request"

Comment: erro 400 já é um começo diz que tem um problema no envio da requisição, talvez da forma atual ela não seja válida.

Comment: Sim... Ai quando uso curl, o retorno é esse: message=Unauthorized.&code=400.0300&cause=Some of required parameters (oauth_consumer_key&oauth_signature&oauth_signature_method&oauth_timestamp&oauth‌​_nonce) absent.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e colcoa essas informações :)

Comment: Ok, espero que alguem ajuda.

Comment: Pode colocar o valor da variável `$curl_post_data` ela tem os campos enviados pelo curl certo?

Comment: sim o problema é que eu não sei o que colocar  lá...
Dá uma lida na documentação pra ver se você consegue entender.

Comment: Depois vou dar uma olhada, aqui é bloqueda kkk

Comment: Ok, agradeço pela a sua ajuda!

Comment: Léo, esses parâmetros em falta precisam ser gerados e enviados juntos com a requisição. Eles fazem parte do fluxo de autenticação via Oauth 1.0. O melhor será utilizar uma lib client em PHP que faça isso, você apenas precisa informar as URLs, o consumer key e secret. Eu consegui fazer funcionar utilizando uma lib. Vou postar uma resposta.

Comment: Ok cara, agradeço muito se poder me ajudar, faz dias estou na luta por esse API porque uso uma antiga e logo vão deixar ela pra lá e vou ficar prejudicado, por isso estou procurando atualizar logo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem parâmetros que são necessários para que o fluxo de autenticação Oauth 1.0 funcione corretamente:

- oauth_signature
- oauth_signature_method
- oauth_timestamp
- oauth‌​‌​_nonce

Ou você preenche todos manualmente ou utiliza uma lib client para consumir o serviço.

No exemplo abaixo vou utilizar uma lib e não vou reinventar a roda:

1. Faça o download da lib (última versão Nov 24, 2010, não se assuste porque Oauth vai na versão 2.0 e o 4shared utiliza a versão 1.0) aqui: https://code.google.com/archive/p/oauth-php/downloads
2. Descompacte o .zip, iremos precisar apenas da pasta `library`. Procure por ela e copie para a raiz do seu projeto.
3. Agora você precisa registrar uma APP no 4Shared (não é preciso preencher o campo `Application domain`, isso será feito no nosso script): http://www.4shared.com/developer/docs/app/
4. Depois de criar a APP, será fornecido os seguintes dados:

   - Consumer Key
   - Consumer Secret
   - Initiate address
   - Authorize address
   - Request token address

Agora precisamos apenas de criar um script para utilizar a lib e consumir o serviço. No mesmo local onde você colocou a pasta `library`, criei um novo arquivo `.php` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php
// Adicionar as bibliotecas, se colocar a pasta library em outro diretório, coloque o caminho correto abaixo. No meu caso a pasta está no mesmo diretório que o arquivo .php
include_once "library/OAuthStore.php";
include_once "library/OAuthRequester.php";

define("FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY", "<KEY>");
define("FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_SECRET", "<SECRET>");
define("FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST", "https://api.4shared.com");
define("FOURSHARED_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL", FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . "/v1_2/oauth/initiate");
define("FOURSHARED_AUTHORIZE_URL", FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . "/v1_2/oauth/authorize");
define("FOURSHARED_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL", FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . "/v1_2/oauth/token");
define('OAUTH_TMP_DIR', function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') ? sys_get_temp_dir() : realpath($_ENV["TMP"]));

//Coloque aqui a URL do servidor que você utiliza para testes. No meu caso eu configurei um vhost e coloquei o caminho para o próprio script.
define("FOURSHARED_OAUTH_CALLBACK", "http://testes.loc/4shared.php");    

//  Inicia o OAuthStore
$options = array(
    'consumer_key' => FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY, 
    'consumer_secret' => FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    'server_uri' => FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST,
    'request_token_uri' => FOURSHARED_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
    'authorize_uri' => FOURSHARED_AUTHORIZE_URL,
    'access_token_uri' => FOURSHARED_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL
);

// Atenção: não armazene os dados em "Session" em produção. 
// Escolha uma base de dados.
OAuthStore::instance("Session", $options);

try
{
    //  Passo 1:  se não existir um OAuth token ainda, precisamos de um.
    if (empty($_GET["oauth_token"]))
    {
        $getAuthTokenParams = array(
            'scope' => FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . '/v1_2',
            'xoauth_displayname' => 'Oauth 4Shared',
            'oauth_callback' => FOURSHARED_OAUTH_CALLBACK
        );

        // Solicita um request token
        $tokenResultParams = OAuthRequester::requestRequestToken(FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY, 0, $getAuthTokenParams);

        // Redireciona para a página de autorização. Aqui o utilizador dará permissões na primeira vez e depois será redirecionado novamente para o seu site.
        header("Location: " . FOURSHARED_AUTHORIZE_URL . "?oauth_token=" . $tokenResultParams['token']);
    }
    else {
        //  Passo 2:  solicitar um access token
        $oauthToken = $_GET["oauth_token"];
        $tokenResultParams = $_GET;

        try {
            OAuthRequester::requestAccessToken(FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY, $oauthToken, 0, 'POST', $_GET);
        }
        catch (OAuthException2 $e)
        {
            var_dump($e);
            return;
        }

        // Vamos solicitar informações do utilizador
        $request = new OAuthRequester(FOURSHARED_OAUTH_HOST . '/v1_2/user', 'GET', $tokenResultParams);
        $result = $request->doRequest(0);
        if ($result['code'] == 200) {
            // Converter string para um objeto json
            $user = json_decode($result['body']);

            // Imprimir em tela o e-mail;
            echo $user->email;
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
}
catch(OAuthException2 $e) {
    echo "OAuthException:  " . $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Não se esqueça de alterar os valores no script acima para as constantes `FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_KEY`, `FOURSHARED_CONSUMER_SECRET` e `FOURSHARED_OAUTH_CALLBACK`.

É preciso melhorar o script, por exemplo, se você fizer refresh no browser após obter o e-mail do utilizador, ocorrerá uma OAuthException.

O erro ocorre porque ao fazer refresh é utilizado o mesmo token para obter um novo access token. Ao gerir isso com uma base de dados, você pode fazer um sistema mais complexo, armazenando o id do utilizador no seu sistema, o access token e a respectiva validade, assim antes de solicitar um novo access token, você verifica se para o utilizador X ainda existe um válido.

Outra ponto é que no exemplo tudo é armazenado em sessão e em produção deve ser guardado em base de dados, justamente para implementar o que escrevi acima.

Você deve estudar um pouco mais a autenticação via Oauth 1.0. Tente entender o fluxo que tudo ficará mais claro.

Links:

- http://oauth.net/core/diagram.png
- http://oauth.net/core/1.0/

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54260/discussion-on-answer-by-filipe-moraes-como-consumir-rest-api-do-4shared-utilizan)